# Charge iPad Pro 12.9 on an USB 3 port?

Tags: ipad, usb, charging

I just read through [Fast Charging iPad Pro 12.9](https://www.macstories.net/ios/testing-apples-29w-usb-c-power-adapter-and-ipad-pro-fast-charging/) and am intrigued.

However I'd like to use the USB 3 port on my MacBook air instead of buying a new power brick just for the iPad Pro.

Has anybody tried to use an USB 3 -> USB C adaptor in conjunction with Apples [USB C to Lightning cable](http://www.apple.com/ie/shop/product/MKQ42ZM/A/usb-c-to-lightning-cable-2m)?

I haven't found an USB 3 to USB C adaptor only USB C to USB 3. Maybe that answers my question already.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's the answer. 
[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_Type-C)

Adapters and cables with a Type-C receptacle are not allowed.([41](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#cite_note-41))

Answer (score 0):

USB3 is able to deliver 0.9A while USB2 is able to deliver 0.5A, so yes, it can charge some power hungry devices quicker. Since the power difference is in the adaptor (which is why big iPad bricks charge iPads quicker than little iPhone bricks), I am doubtful that getting a USB3->USBC adaptor will make a difference. The power is in the adaptor (brick).